# C# - SQL Server - record locking

Tags: c#, sql-server, locking

I'd like to ask for suggestion, what would the recommended ways of addressing below problem, so I can do investigation and reading the right information.
A user would be able to select an item from a drop down and press Edit button to change data for selected item. At this moment, I’d need to lock the record for other users (what would be preferred ways?). If another user tries to edit same item, show a message that it is locked by other user.
Handling app / pc crashes to unlock the record (best solutions?)

Regards

Piotr

Comment: Search for discussions about "pessimistic locking vs. optimistic locking". There is no "best" way as much depends on your goals. Pessimistic locking can be an impediment to users working efficiently and quickly and concurrently - think carefully about that approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When users are editing rows, you should use optimistic concurrency, instead of server-side locking.  Under optimistic concurrency the client filters the update or delete using additional columns that act as a "concurrency token" to ensure that the row hasn't been updated by any other user.  eg

```
update T set a = @a, b = @b
where Id = @id and RowVersionColumn = @rowversion;
select @@rowcount RowsAffected;
```

If the update or delete affects zero rows, then the client knows some other user has changed the row, and they can reload the current version and decide whether to re-submit the change.

In SQL Server a [rowversion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/rowversion-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) column is often used as the concurrency token.

See, eg [Handling Concurrency Conflicts in EF Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/concurrency)